# Play .mov file on custom player

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have code for play .mov file from live URL. it's working fine 
for that i have use UIWebView, and i have also set thumbnail and video, when i click on webview the file are playing in Quick player in iPhone - so my question is , Is it possible to play the file without using Quick player (on UIwebview or something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also play Directly from URL in MPMoviePlayerController with live streaming.
No need to download that video.

```
self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/video/myVideo.wav"]];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load a webpage within UIWebView then if the video is specified in the page using the  tag then you can play it inline within the UIWebView page if you want.

make sure to set this

```
self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

and also put this in the html

```
webkit-playsinline
```

i.e. like this

```
<video id="theVideo" controls width="180" height="160" src="sample_mpeg4.mp4"  webkit-playsinline></video>
```